# DoDragDrop - get target window handle

Tags: .net, windows, handle, drag-and-drop

I'm using the following code to `dragdrop` data from `listbox` into another applications:

```
Dim data As New DataObject(DataFormats.UnicodeText, ListBox1.Text)
ListBox1.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy Or DragDropEffects.Copy)
```

How can I get a handle of the window that receives the data?

I'm looking to build something like "Finder Tool" in Microsoft Spy++.

Comment: Found this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/windowfinder.aspx

Comment: Are you able to get the drop location address. Like if you try to drop in Desktop can you get the physical address of Desktop like C:\Users\XXX\Desktop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you can know in which window the drop occurred. This is not the philosophy of drag&drop.

Are you thinking of the 'target icon' that Spy++ shows when you can find a window by moving over 
the desktop ?

This is not a drag&drop operation, I guess Spy++ sets the current window cursor to the 'target', captures the mouse, and uses the hit testing Windows API to ask what is under the cursor.